# showing blank page in php, not redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, logout

I don't know where I am wrong with this PHP code. When i click on log in in my log in Page the username and password gonna check in this code den it should redirect to 'dashboard.php' but the process gets end on this page. It shows blank. Please can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

---

```
<?php
include('db.php');
flush();
//error_reporting(1);
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);


$sql="SELECT * FROM user_qc WHERE qc_user_name='$username' and qc_pass='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['log'] = 'in';
$_SESSION['username']= $username;
header("Location:dashboard.php");
}
?>
```

---

Comment: Unrelated: Please beware for SQL injections as your code is vulnerable to them.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Variables should be used in double quotes("") while using inside MySQL query.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
flush();
//error_reporting(1);
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);


$sql="SELECT * FROM user_qc WHERE qc_user_name='".$username."' AND qc_pass='".$password."'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['log'] = 'in';
$_SESSION['username']= $username;
header("Location:dashboard.php");
}
?>
```

Don't use mysql rather use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Don't post insecure code on StackOverflow.  People copy and paste code here all the time.  As you know, concatenating data into SQL is extremely dangerous and unreliable.  At a minimum, escape the data.

Comment: @Brad I have made my changes & escaped the data.

Answer (score 0):

change your header and use "" in $sql
i think this will solve the problem.
sorry for bad english.

```
  <?php

   include('db.php');

     flush();

      //error_reporting(1);

      $username=$_POST['username'];

       $password=sha1($_POST['password']);

         $username = stripslashes($username);

          $password = stripslashes($password);



          $sql="SELECT * FROM user_qc WHERE qc_user_name='".$username."' AND qc_pass='".$password."'";
         $result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);


          $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);


         if($count==1){
         session_start();

          $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';

       $_SESSION['username']= $username;
             header("Location:http://yoursite/.../dashboard.php");
       }
        ?>
```